# XamlParseException: ''Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, exception

Using VS-2017 and working on a WPF (MVVM Pattern) solution shared in TFS with other developers

I'am getting this issue since I downloaded  a new version of the solution from TFS

The solution compiles correctly and works fine on other developer's machines who work on this solution, except mine.

ExceptionTrace:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
  HResult=0x80131501
  Message='Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' 
threw an exception.' Line number '33' and line position '10'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, 
IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)

Inner Exception 1:
NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
```

Details:

```
-       $exception  {"'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.' Line number '33' and line position '10'."}    System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
+       BaseUri null    System.Uri
+       Data    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
        HResult -2146233087 int
        HelpLink    null    string
+       IPForWatsonBuckets  0x000007fee1c3a3c4  System.UIntPtr
+       InnerException  {"The method or operation is not implemented."}  
System.Exception {System.NotImplementedException}
    IsTransient false   bool
    KeyContext  null    object
    LineNumber  33  int
    LinePosition    10  int
    Message "'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.' Line number '33' and line position '10'."  string
    NameContext null    string
    RemoteStackTrace    null    string
    Source  "PresentationFramework" string
    StackTrace  "   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)"  string
+       TargetSite  {Void RewrapException(System.Exception, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfo, System.Uri)} System.Reflection.MethodBase {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}
    UidContext  null    string
    WatsonBuckets   null    object
    _HResult    -2146233087 int
+       _baseUri    null    System.Uri
    _className  null    string
+       _data   {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    _dynamicMethods null    object
+       _exceptionMethod    {Void RewrapException(System.Exception, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfo, System.Uri)} System.Reflection.MethodBase {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}
    _exceptionMethodString  null    string
    _helpURL    null    string
+       _innerException {"The method or operation is not implemented."} System.Exception {System.NotImplementedException}
+       _ipForWatsonBuckets 0x000007fee1c3a3c4  System.UIntPtr
    _keyContext null    object
    _lineNumber 33  int
    _linePosition   10  int
    _message    "'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.' Line number '33' and line position '10'."  string
    _nameContext    null    string
    _remoteStackIndex   0   int
    _remoteStackTraceString null    string
+       _safeSerializationManager   {System.Runtime.Serialization.SafeSerializationManager} System.Runtime.Serialization.SafeSerializationManager
    _source "PresentationFramework" string
+       _stackTrace {sbyte[48]} object {sbyte[]}
    _stackTraceString   null    string
    _uidContext null    string
    _watsonBuckets  null    object
    _xcode  -532462766  int
+       _xptrs  0x0000000000000000  System.IntPtr
+       Static members
```

I think that the problem is not in the code but in my machine, because now even the old versions of the solution (that used to work fine) are getting this same Exception and don't compile.

**Can someone help me to discover what's going wrong !?**

Comment: If you download older version from TFS everything works?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk  Older versions from TFS  dont work for me but work on other machines.

Comment: @mm8 , there are 13 projects inside this solution, I can't tell you if is  there thrown  NotImplementedException in the code

Comment: Why not? And how do you think someone else that doesn't even have access to your code is going to be able to tell? Just search for the word in visual studio. Or debug your code.

Comment: @mm8 I just verified, and there are no NotImplementedException  thrown in entire solution

Comment: Are you use the latest version of VS?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk yes i Updated the VS to version 15.8.1 (the latest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed the issue

I moved the solution to a new directory and i didn't know that a "Carmenta" folder is added to the project directory.

So I just edited the environment variable and it works fine